# Collect results from groups to one string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to parse weather html page for Openhab.
This is significant part of whole html:

```
                <!-- Amount of Sun -->
            <tr>
                <td class="label_det">
<span class="sum">∑</span> <span class="unit">in u</span>
</td>


                            <td class="sunamount">

                    10.2
                    </td>


                            <td class="sunamount">

                    10.6
                    </td>


                            <td class="sunamount">

                    5.9
                    </td>


                            <td class="sunamount">

                    6.8
                    </td>


                            <td class="dgrey sunamount">

                    6.8
                    </td>


                            <td class="dgrey sunamount">

                    5.4
                    </td>


                            <td class="sunamount">

                    5
                    </td>

            </tr>
```

I would like to collect all numbers into one string, I understand that it's, perhaps, not possible, but may be...
So something like this: '10.2 10.6 5.9 6.8 6.8 5.4 5'

Example of full html and my current regex is here: https://regex101.com/r/nrzPHU/1

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but you don't need a regex for what you want to do. You can just iterate over all the data inside the table with the class of ```sunamount``` and grab the values.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, but you can try `<td class\=\".*?sunamount\">\s+(\d*\.?\d+)\s+<\/td>`

Comment: This parsing is in Openhab environment, I don't know it's language. This is a reason why I want to use raw regex and create one simple string.

Answer (score 0):

You need named capture groups. Named capture groups allow you to specify a given part in regex with a name to extract it later. A named capture group starts with (? then followed by the regex and ended with ).

```
<td class\=\".*?sunamount\">\s+(?<amount>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+<\/td>
```

You would then be able to extract the amount by applying your regex to the input and picking the group named amount out of it.

Reading about [OpenHab online](https://www.openhab.org/addons/transformations/regex/) I'm not sure they support named capture groups. So an alternative would be using the regex above to match all lines with amounts in the input. Then using a regex replace on that matched string. So something like...

Use this regex to get amounts:

```
<td class\=\".*?sunamount\">\s+\d+(\.\d+)?\s+<\/td>
```

Use this regex on the result of the regex above to replace the non amounts (and replace them with an empty string to delete them):

```
([\s]|<td class=".*?">|<\/td>)
```